Difference between 'source', 'chroot' and 'session' schroot namespaces
From schroot man page:

Source chroots
Some chroot types, for example LVM snapshots and Btrfs snapshots,
provide session-managed copy-on-write snapshots of the chroot. These
also provide a source chroot to allow easy access to the filesystem
used as a source for snapshotting. These are regular chroots as well,
just with the snapshotting disabled. For a chroot named “sid-snapshot”
(i.e. with a fully qualified name of “chroot:sid-snapshot”), there
will also be a corresponding source chroot named
“source:sid-snapshot”. Earlier versions of schroot provided source
chroots with a ‘-source’ suffix. These are also provided for
compatibility. In this example, this would be called
“chroot:sid-snapshot-source”. These compatibility names will be
dropped in a future version, so programs and scripts should switch to
using the namespace-qualified names rather than the old suffix.

$ schroot -i -c chroot:foo-amd64
  ─── Chroot ───
  Name                                 foo-amd64
  Description                          foo-amd64
  Type                                 directory
  Message Verbosity                    normal
  Users                                
  Groups                               root
  Root Users                           
  Root Groups                          root
  Aliases                              
  Preserve Environment                 true
  Default Shell                        
  Environment Filter                   ^(BASH_ENV|CDPATH|ENV|HOSTALIASES|IFS|KRB5_CONFIG|KRBCONFDIR|KRBTKFILE|KRB_CONF|LD_.*|LOCALDOMAIN|NLSPATH|PATH_LOCALE|RES_OPTIONS|TERMINFO|TERMINFO_DIRS|TERMPATH)$
  Run Setup Scripts                    true
  Configuration Profile                proff1
  Script Configuration                 
  Session Managed                      true
  Session Cloned                       true
  Session Purged                       false
  Directory                            /srv/devel/schroot/foo-amd64
  Personality                          undefined
  User Modifiable Keys                 
  Root Modifiable Keys                 
  User Data                            
    setup.config                       proff1/config
    setup.copyfiles                    proff1/copyfiles
    setup.fstab                        proff1/fstab
    setup.nssdatabases                 proff1/nssdatabases
  Filesystem Union Type                overlay
  Filesystem Union Overlay Directory   /var/lib/schroot/union/overlay
  Filesystem Union Underlay Directory  /var/lib/schroot/union/underlay
  Source Users                         
  Source Groups                        
  Source Root Users                    root admin
  Source Root Groups                   root admin

$ schroot -i -c source:foo-amd64
  ─── Source ───
  Name                   foo-amd64
  Description            foo-amd64 (source chroot)
  Type                   directory
  Message Verbosity      normal
  Users                  
  Groups                 
  Root Users             root admin
  Root Groups            root admin
  Aliases                
  Preserve Environment   true
  Default Shell          
  Environment Filter     ^(BASH_ENV|CDPATH|ENV|HOSTALIASES|IFS|KRB5_CONFIG|KRBCONFDIR|KRBTKFILE|KRB_CONF|LD_.*|LOCALDOMAIN|NLSPATH|PATH_LOCALE|RES_OPTIONS|TERMINFO|TERMINFO_DIRS|TERMPATH)$
  Run Setup Scripts      true
  Configuration Profile  proff1
  Script Configuration   
  Session Managed        true
  Session Cloned         false
  Session Purged         false
  Directory              /srv/devel/schroot/foo-amd64
  Personality            undefined
  User Modifiable Keys   
  Root Modifiable Keys   
  User Data              
    setup.config         proff1/config
    setup.copyfiles      proff1/copyfiles
    setup.fstab          proff1/fstab
    setup.nssdatabases   proff1/nssdatabases

I don't have a concrete understanding of what's the difference between these namespaces. Based on what I've understood, source namespaces are like the base layer for building actual chroot. source: chroot is what is stored in /srv/devel/schroot/foo-amd64. If source: is the base, I don't understand what chroot: does as session: is a layer on top of that source: chroot and that' when Filesystem Union Overlay Directory gets mounted.
Like if source: is the base layer and session: is the ephemeral layer, why do we need chroot: then? (The chroot: namespace)
Overall, this is really confusing to me and although I understand bits, I don't understand the complete picture. Can someone explain what each of these namespaces represent and if they are different copies, where are they stored?

Can someone explain this to me?
